# Custom init method returns nil on second invocation

Tags: objective-c, initialization, null

I have a custom class MBIKioku with an init method like this:

```
- (id)initWithSize:(int)size
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        // do stuffs
    }
    return self; // breakpoint A
}
```

And I use it within my view controller like so

```
@implementation MBIKiokuViewController
{
    MBIKioku *kioku;
    // other instance variables
}

- (void)loadLevel:(int)level
{
    kioku = [[MBIKioku alloc] initWithSize:3];
    // do stuffs (breakpoint B)
}
```

The first time I call loadLevel:, everything works perfectly. However, the second time it returns nil!

I tried putting a break before return self (breakpoint A) and after the initialization (breakpoint B) and run it through the debugger. Here's what I learned:

- You need to actually press continue twice on breakpoint A before being able to continue the execution. The first time you press continue, self will be set to nil. Dunno what voodoo is going on in the background (some ARC stuffs?). However on the first time initWithSize: is called, the caller properly gets a non-nil value.
- The second time initWithSize: is called, the caller always gets nil! Therefore the value of kioku on breakpoint B will be nil on the second execution.

This is actually a piece of code that's working fine on my other project but somehow fails on my second project.

Any clues on what's happening here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have a custom setter or getter for kioku?  Also, what is the superclass of MBIKioku?  NSObject or something else?

Comment: the superclass is NSObject. I don't have custom setter/getter, but I do have some methods that behave like setter and getter, e.g.: "- (int)dataAtRow:(int)row col:(int)col" and "- (void)setDelegate:(id<MBIKiokuDelegate>) del"